# Count Total Number of Items based on Condition

Tags: java, android, android-listview

In my program i am using ListView and in each and every row i am **showing one of the image icon (Yes/No) based on condition** i am playing with, and using below ***code to get total number of item(s) in a list*** (includes both :- Yes & No) Icons.

```
String totalNumberOfItemsInAList = ""+ lstView.getAdapter().getCount();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total number of Items are:" + totalNumberOfItemsInAList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But what if i only want to know total number of items in a list which contains Yes Icon, my code looks like this:

```
     private SparseBooleanArray flags = new SparseBooleanArray();

     // to upload whole list
     for(int position = 0; position < lstView.getAdapter().getCount(); position++)
                 {
                     flags.put(position, true);   
                 }

                 ((BaseAdapter) lstView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();        
            }
        });

        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        listSDCardImages = fetchSDCardImages();

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSDCardImages);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ListSDCardImagesAdapter(this));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total number of Items are:" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Condition, i am using to show **Yes/No icons** is something like this:

```
if(resultAvailable)
{
holder.colView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_yes);
}
else
{
holder.colView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_no);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
yesImagesCount=0;
```

variable in your activity and increment this count in this code as

```
if(resultAvailable)
{
    holder.colView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_yes);
    yesImagesCount++;
}
else
{
    holder.colView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_no);
}
```

And Finally display toast as

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total number of Yes  Icons are:" + String.valueOf(yesImagesCount), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: but in this code where you have written code to count Yes icon images ?

Comment: please share your final code with me, which you think i should try